# How to select Partition Key in Azure Cosmos in case volume is very low ( total records < 50k)

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have read all documents available on Microsoft websites and the internet but most of them talk about large data but my requirement is quite small.

I am trying to save Customer Onboarding data. Before Customer onboards we assign him his company Id and User Id and admin role and default environment. The company can create multiple dummy environments to test. E.g. Dev1, Stage And Test123, etc, and Onboarding will be done on Environment Level.

Onboarding JSON

```
{
    "companyId": "Company123",
    "environment": "stg1",
    "userId": "User123",
    "startDate": 1212121212,
    "modifiedDate": 1212121212,
    "uniqueId": "<companyId_UserId>"
}
```

Onboarding can be done at Environment Level. As per data a Company can have at most 10 to 15 environments. In the above document User Id is just metadata to check which user started onboarding on Environment stg1.

Initially I thought of using the company Id as partition key but in this case each logical partition will have at most 15 records.

My Cosmos Queries will contain Company Id & Environment Id as a filter.

Is it a good approach? Or Should I generate synthetic Partition Key using Hash Function and limit logical partitions to 10 or 20.

Which one is faster?

- A large number of Logical Partitions but all partitions contains 10 to 15 Documents
- A Less number of Logical Partitions but partitions contains more number of Documents.

My complete data size is about < 1 GB so please don't assume that we will reach the limit of "logical partition limit 10 GB" here.

My other Queries is

- With Azure SDK In the case of inserting new document my RU is 7.67 but in the case of upsert it is 10.9. Is there any way to reduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collection is never going to go over 20GB then what you use as a partition key is not as critical because all of your data (and your queries) will reside on a single physical partition. Partition keys (and partitioning) are all about scale (which is why we always talk about them in the context of large amounts of data or high volume of operations).

In a read-heavy workload, choosing a partition key that is used in all of your query where clauses is a safe strategy, in your case a synthetic key of `environmentId-companyId` is a good choice. If this is a write heavy workload then you also want the partition key values to distriubte writes across partitions. But again, if this is a small collection then this matters little here.

Your `id` property is fine as it will work having the same `companyId-userId` value with different partition key values which is what I assume you want. You also can do a point read with `environmentId`, `companyId` and `userId` if you have all three which you should do as much as possible rather than queries when looking for a single item. Even though this collection will not grow, based upon what you say, the partition strategy here should allow it to scale should you ever want it to.

Upserts are always going to be more expensive than an insert because it's two operations rather than one. The only way to reduce the cost of writes is to create a custom index policy and exclude paths you never query on. But based upon the example document in your post, a custom index policy will not get you any improvement.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: wdym always reside on a single physical partition? what if you scale to 100.000 RU\s? they should be distributed across several physical partitions

Answer (score 1):

Logical partition limit is not 20gb, as far as I'm aware. As far as I know from the talks with the product group developing cosmos db there is no harm in creating as many partitions as you need, just keep in mind you should avoid cross-partition queries at all costs (so design the data in such a fashion that you will never have to do cross partition queries).

so logical partition for a customer makes sense, unless you want to do queries across all customers. but given the data set size it should not have a tremendous impact. either way, both approaches will work. I'd say creating a synthetic key is only needed when you cannot find a reasonable key without generating it